# How to automatically build a framework when a project is built

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I created a cocoa touch framework project in Xcode7, then I added a target of iOS app as a sample project for using the framework.

When I build the sample project after making changes to the framework, the framework does not automatically build, so the app links to the old version. Is there a way to automate this?

I've tried adding the framework to the  "embeded binaries" and "linked frameworks and libraries" sections of the sample project but it does not work.

However, if I start out creating an app project, then add a framework target, the build process is correctly automated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

turns out I relaunched Xcode and it worked.

Just make sure the framework appears in the three secitons of the app target: 'target dependencies', "embeded binaries" and "linked frameworks and libraries".